# Overloading a function to take true_type or false_type parameter vs using an if check?

Tags: c++, boolean, overloading

Are there any benefits of overloading a method/function to take `true_type` or `false_type` parameter, compared to using one `if` statement?
I see more and more code using overloaded methods with `true_type` and `false_type` parameters.

A short example using `if` statement

```
void coutResult(bool match)
{
    if (match)
        cout << "Success." << endl;
    else
        cout << "Failure." << endl;
}

bool match = my_list.contains(my_value);
coutResult(match);
```

Compared to using an overloaded function:

```
void coutResult(true_type)
{
    cout << "Success." << endl;
}

void coutResult(false_type)
{
    cout << "Failure." << endl;
}

bool match = my_list.contains(my_value);
coutResult(match);
```

Comment: There can be reasons for doing this in `constexpr` functions that are used at compile-time. Are the examples you found doing this at compile time? (That wouldn't work with output to STDOUT, of course.)

Comment: @jogojapan I've seen it being used dozens of times, but the latest was in the stl `algorithm` library's `find` function, as seen on [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-7-of-n) at around 15:00. I'm pretty sure it's used at compile time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your second example code wouldn't compile, which is a symptom of the difference between *compile-time overload resolution* and *run-time conditional branching* to "choose" which code to execute.

- "Overloading a function to take `true_type` or `false_type` parameter" allows to make this choice *at compile time* if the decision only depends on *types and compile-time constants*.
- "Using an `if` check" is necessary if the choice can't be done until *run time* when some *variable values* are known.

In your example the `bool match = my_list.contains(my_value)` is obviously not known before running the program, so you can't use overloading.

But the difference is most important for **templates**, where the choice is not only "which path to execute" but "which code to *instantiate and compile* and then call". The code from your [linked video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-7-of-n) is rather in this spirit:

Consider this (wrong) code (omitting `#include`s and `std::`s for brevity):

```
template<typename InIt>
typename iterator_traits<InIt>::difference_type
distance(InIt first, InIt last)
{
    // Make code shorter
    typedef typename iterator_traits<InIt>::difference_type Diff;
    typedef typename iterator_traits<InIt>::iterator_category Tag;

    // Choice
    if (is_same<Tag, random_access_iterator_tag>::value)
    {
        return last - first;
    }
    else
    {
        Diff n = 0;
        while (first != last) {
            ++first;
            ++n;
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

There are at least two problems here:

- If you try to call it with iterators that are *not* random-access (e.g. `std::list<T>::iterator`), it will actually *fail to compile* (with an error pointing the line `return last - first;`). The compiler has to instantiate and compile the entire function body, including *both* the `if` and the `else` branches (even though only one is to be executed), and the expression `last - first` is invalid for non-RA iterators.
- Even if that compiled, we would be doing a test at *run time* (with the related overhead) for a condition that we could have tested as soon as *compile time*, and compiling unneeded code parts. (The compiler may be able to optimize that, but that's the concept.)

To fix it you can do:

```
// (assume needed declarations...)

template<typename InIt>
typename iterator_traits<InIt>::difference_type
distance(InIt first, InIt last)
{
    // Make code shorter
    typedef typename iterator_traits<InIt>::iterator_category Tag;

    // Choice
    return distanceImpl(first, last, is_same<Tag, random_access_iterator_tag>());
}

template<typename InIt>
typename iterator_traits<InIt>::difference_type
distanceImpl(InIt first, InIt last, true_type)
{
    return last - first;
}

template<typename InIt>
typename iterator_traits<InIt>::difference_type
distanceImpl(InIt first, InIt last, false_type)
{
    // Make code shorter
    typedef typename iterator_traits<InIt>::difference_type Diff;

    Diff n = 0;
    while (first != last) {
        ++first;
        ++n;
    }
    return n;
}
```

or alternatively (possible here) with types directly:

```
/* snip */
distance(InIt first, InIt last)
{
    /* snip */
    return distanceImpl(first, last, Tag());
}

/* snip */
distanceImpl(InIt first, InIt last, random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    return last - first;
}

/* snip */
distanceImpl(InIt first, InIt last, input_iterator_tag)
{
    /* snip */
    Diff n = 0;
    /* snip */
    return n;
}
```

Now only the "correct" `distanceImpl` will be instantiated and called (the choice being done at compile time).

This works because the types (e.g. `InIt` or `Tag`) are known at compile-time, and `is_same<Tag, random_access_iterator_tag>::value` is a constant that is known at compile-time too. The compiler can resolve which overload is to be called, only based on types (that's overload resolution).

Note: Even though the "tags" are passed by value, they are only used as unnamed, unused parameters for "dispatch" (their value is not used, only their type) and the compiler can optimize them out.

You can also read **Item 47: Use traits classes for information about types** from Scott Meyers' [*Effective C++, Third Edition*](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html).

Answer (score 3):

Such overloading is useful for compile-time optimizations. Note that in the example you are referring to a `typedef` is used to define a **type** which matches `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`. This type is evaluated in compile time. Creating a value of the type in a subsequent function call is necessary just to call the function: you cannot call a function with a type as an argument.

You cannot perform overloading based on a **value** of a variable. Overloading is performed based on type.

The code

```
bool match = my_list.contains(my_value);
coutResult(match);
```

doesn't compile as there is no `coutResult(bool)` function:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘coutResult(bool)’ 
note: candidates are: void coutResult(std::true_type) 
note:                 void coutResult(std::false_type)
```

So, if your expression can be evaluated in compile-time, you may benefit from overloading functions for `true_type` and `false_type` thus removing additional checks in run-time. But if the expression is not a constant, you must use `if`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, generally you can not explicitly derive the object type because of the lack of `Reflection` property. If you want to operate according to object type, you need such kind of function overloading.

If you want to use `If` statement, you need to define some extra member or method for each related class to get class information which may not be permitted for some contexts and it introduces extra overhead ofcourse. As a more practical way, `typeid` can be used instead of this extra member and the object's id can be compared with the intended class id at run-time.

Moreover, If the classes are quite different from each other (like not having a common base) and they are defined and designed for entirely separate pusposes, it is a good design practice to handle them in separate methods instead of a single conditional.

Comment: This is a nice answer to why overloaded functions are useful. However, the original question is why to overload a function for two single-constant types (some kind of subsets of `bool`) to get rid of `if` statement.